# Mathematical operations such as "Reflection in Line" with FOSS Linux tools such as Inkscape, Gimp or Blender?

Tags: gimp, inkscape, blender

In Gimp, I could do this by `"Layer/Transform/180 rotation"` and then `"Layer/Transform/Flip vertically"` -- and then with some mouse, putting things together but it is slow. I am now looking for simpler solution, particularly interested in Inkscape but also interested in other FOSS tools such as Gimp and Blender.

My goal is to save time by this `"reflection in line"` i.e. by reusing. I want to do just half of the work and then get the other half easily. Similarly, suppose I do a four-times symmetric shape, I want to reuse the one piece to get the 360 degrees' shape.

**How to do mathematical operations such as reflection in line?**

[image]

Comment: erm... huh? Is there a question there?

Comment: I did not down vote. I still don't see a clear question here.

Comment: Sorry, I don't wish to help based upon your attitude. good luck to you.

Comment: @hhh I downvoted your question because it is overly simple and easily searchable.  If you google "inkscape reflection", there are pages of results with tutorials on how to create what you are trying to do.  In fact, the entire process involves clicking a single button that is visible in the default tool menus.

Comment: @hhh It's exceptionally easy for you to delete your ranting, and somewhat insulting comments... then post something new in order to appear less offensive than you were being. Plainly put, I rarely extend a hand to anyone who screams and insults.

Comment: Please, remove the comments here. I will do my best if there is still something uncertain, haven't yet solved the prob here but trying.

Comment: @hhh Although I am not totally certain if it applies to GraphicDesign.SE, [according to this](http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/1043/10691) a question may be closed if *"a search engine can answer the question"*.

Answer (score 1):

Inkscape: Just make a copy of the object (Space bar+click), then flip the copy horizontally (H) and move it next to the original. (Activate the box snapping to make it easier to position it).

Sorry, didn't read the question properly.

The operation requires 2 keystrokes and one flick of the mouse, so it hardly seems worth it to look for something else. You can do the same on a large number of objects just by selecting them together...

What are you trying to do that requires this to be a one click function?

Comment: How did you do the `"selection"` in inkscape? I can do the copy and horizontal-reflection but cannot find the Gimp-style crop or selection, investigating...anyway +1 for nice combos, wish I could find things from the menus also, searching.

Comment: @hhh Selection is simple: Left click to select one. Shift+click to select more. Alternatively, you can use the "select" tool (F1) and "draw" a square around the objects you want to select.

Comment: For cropping, you have to think differently: Draw a path over the path you want to crop, select both and use "Difference" from the path menu (Ctrl+-). If the object you want to crop is not a path, you have to convert it to path first (Shift+ctrl+c)

Comment: Are you trying to edit a raster image? if so, inkscape is not the tool you need

Comment: Good point, it may complicate things a bit. potrace/autotrace to vector form or wacom-inkling (but proprietary vector-form) and then changes with Inkscape. Imagemagick works at least with raster images, investigating. Not sure whether Inkscape works with Wacom-inkling -format something like wci but anyway, good point -- anyway I tried with vector images (SVG) the cropping but cannot still get it working...

Comment: @hhh Spend some time on youtube watching tutorials and try to do them. You seem to be missing basic data about the working of vector graphics and no amount of answering will help until you learn a bit more.

Comment: You have to group the elements first, before copy/flipping. Else you end up with all flippings being done for all elements individually.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do the reflection in line. For batch-processing, you should use [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org). For casual editing, please, consult the other answer with Inkscape solution. For more serious thing, you may want to use Mirror operation and Blender like [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ooKF4hxjaSM).

**Imagemagick, example tested in Ubuntu**

> ```
> $ cat /proc/version 
> Linux version 3.2.0-24-generic (buildd@yellow) (gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) ) #37-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 25 08:43:22
> ```
>
> UTC 2012
>       $ sudo apt-get install imagemagick
>
> Firstly, I have right-sided image from which I generate the left-hand
>   side with the following one-liner.
>
> ```
> $ convert -flop right.png left.png
> ```
>
> [image]
>
> ...getting the other pic:
>
> [image]
>
> And then just the join, here it is possible to do other things but
>   showing only the reflection-in-line. Now you can continue with other
>   tools such as Gimp or Inkscape. Good thing with this method is that it
>   is easy to automate with cron, for example, all images in certain dir
>   getting line-reflected-joined. Smile!
>
> ```
> $ convert +append left.png right.png smile.png
> ```
>
> [image]

**Further information**

1. Reflection with Imagemagick [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198928/imagemagick-reflection).
2. Blender Mirror operation [here](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Manual/Modifiers/Generate/Mirror) and example about using mirror operation [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ooKF4hxjaSM).